# Why can I not get a successful search

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having trouble with the LIKE statement in my query in MYSQLI. It seems like it is not finding any terms that would go into the LIKE statement. I am trying to bind the parameters into the LIKE statement but my question is that am I setting up the LIKE statement in mysqli incorrectly?

The strange thing is that if I output the query and insert it into SQL, and just change the '?' to a term such as '%AAB%', it works fine in SQL as the it does display the records consisting the term AAB. The problem is that it is not working in PHP,mysqli as that it is not showing any records at all if I type in AAB in the textbox. It keeps stating "Sorry, No Question were found from the Search".
Does anybody know why this is?

Below is the code (I have connected to db using mysqli):

```
<form action="previousquestions.php" method="get">
<p>Search: <input type="text" name="questioncontent" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['questioncontent']) ? $_GET['questioncontent'] : ''; ?>" onchange="return trim(this)" /></p>
      <p><input id="searchquestion" name="searchQuestion" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
      </form>


<?php 

if (isset($_GET['searchQuestion'])) {

$searchquestion = $_GET['questioncontent'];
$terms = explode(" ", $searchquestion);

$questionquery = "SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE ";

$i=0;

$whereArray = array();
$orderByArray = array();
$orderBySQL = "";
$paramString = "";

//loop through each term


 foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    $whereArray[] = $each;
    $orderByArray[] = $each; 
    $paramString .= 'ss';
    //if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement
    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";
    } else {
        //If more than 1 term then add an OR statement
        $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";
        $orderBySQL .= ",";
    }

    $orderBySQL .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ,1,0)";

}  

$questionquery .= "GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY " . $orderBySQL;
$questionquery .= " DESC ";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($questionquery)or die($mysqli->error); 

function makeValuesReferenced(&$arr){ 
    $refs = array(); 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
        $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
    return $refs; 

}

$ref = array_merge((array)$paramString, $whereArray, $orderByArray);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), makeValuesReferenced($ref));


    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionContent); 
    $questionnum = $stmt->num_rows();

        if($questionnum ==0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, No Questions were found from this Search</p>";
    }
    else{

      $output = "";
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$output .= "
      <tr>
      <td class='questiontd'>$dbQuestionContent</td>
      </tr>";
        }
        $output .= "        </table>";

        echo $output;

  }


?>
```

Comment: what does this mean: `LIKE ?`

Comment: @MattK: `?` is a mysqli placeholder for where a parameter will be bound using `bind_param`.

Comment: ah, ic. learned something new!

Comment: Your failure to `htmlspecialchars()` your `$_GET['questioncontent']` in your form input is an XSS vulnerability, by the way.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like mysqli is escaping your `%` characters, or something equivalent is happening as part of the client/server communication.  Try this:

```
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;
    $whereArray[] = $each;
    $orderByArray[] = $each; 
    $paramString .= 'ss';
    //if only 1 term entered then perform this LIKE statement
    if ($i == 1){
        $questionquery .= "q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";
    } else {
        //If more than 1 term then add an OR statement
        $questionquery .= "OR q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ";
        $orderBySQL .= ",";
    }
    $orderBySQL .= "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ,1,0)"; 
}
```

You do realize your `ORDER BY` clause is doing absolutely nothing useful, right?

Comment: I forgot to put "DESC" at end of the ORDER BY that's why, I will test your code and get back to you :), thanks

Comment: Good effort but no luck, still can't display a successful search for a term, The output of the query and parameters is this currently if trying to search for a single term: `SELECT q.QuestionContent FROM Question q WHERE q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') GROUP BY q.QuestionId, q.SessionId ORDER BY IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') ,1,0) DESC ss` and it is still displaying the message `Sorry, No Questions were found from this Search` which should only appear if no rows are found but it should be able to find some rows as tested in mySQL database

Comment: I will update code in question so you can now see what it looks like

Comment: @user1394925: Is `ss` really appearing on the end of your query?  If so, I would expect it to be producing a SQL syntax error.

Comment: No I echoed both the query "$questionquery" and the parameter "$paramString". they are completely separate, I just echoed them nxt to each other

Comment: @user1394925: Ah, I see.  No idea, then.  I'd start debugging by executing a fake query with a `WHERE` clause that's always true and thereby making sure that your DB interface methodology is working at all.

Comment: I know the SQL is correct in terms of where Clause and all that because it works in SQL. I don't know why it doesn't work in php. Can I send u a link 2 the app so you can see 4 Urself?

Comment: @user1394925: It wouldn't be relevant, and what I just recommended to you was to test the DB interface methodology, not the SQL.

Comment: @user1394925: You also shouldn't post links to the app here until you've fixed your XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Ok then, can I ask you what you mean by db interface methodology?

Comment: @user1394925: The PHP code you're using to talk to the database.  If a query with a trivial `WHERE` clause retrieves results, then that localizes the problem to your `WHERE` clause.  Right now, the problem could be anywhere.